# making plug-in allows you to navigate and explore geographic data on a 3D globe using a web browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jquery-plugins, google-chrome-extension, three.js

I make a small project using three.js library and i want to make javascript plugin to load 3D big models and java script API on client side as google earth plugin to run faster, The image of downloaded googel earth plugin:

[image]
Thanks In Advance

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Yea dont get at all what you want to do. And wheres the code?

Comment: I do online 3D project and i want to load models as in google earth but i did not have any code about what shall i do, please help me to start!

Answer (score -1):

Here's where you should start ...

You have to use [Google Earth API](https://developers.google.com/earth/) 
[This page](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=earth#hello,_earth) is awesome, in it you may try [interactive sample codes](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=earth#hello,_earth) 
You may find [Developer Guide here](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/index), it will help you start 
And you may find some [code samples here](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/examples), inspect sample codes  
Try these links, and come back with more specific question when you have one. 
Hope these may help you start.